# Stop xubuntu launching loads of stuff at startup

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I have an aging (and ailing) laptop running xubuntu.  Often it locks up and i have to hard-reboot it, which isn't the problem i'm asking about here (i accept it as part of using an old laptop).  The problem is that when it starts up it launches a few command window apps, each with loads of tabs open, and a few nautilus windows, again with tabs, and some other stuff that i don't want.

In the systen preferences (Xfce 4 settings manager) there's a list of apps to autostart.  But, nautilus and the terminal aren't in there.  In the next tab, "Session", there's a list of open apps which it considers to be part of the current session.  I assume this is what's driving the opening of the various windows on startup - it's trying to resurrect some old saved session.

I don't want Xfce to try to resurrect an old session, EVER. Can anyone tell me where to find the config to tell xubuntu to stop doing this?

My xubuntu version is

```
Xfce 4 Desktop Environment
version 4.6.1 (Xfce 4.6)
```

thanks, max

Answer (score 0):

1. Open settings manager
2. Select Session and Startup

Then select which apps you would like to auto start with the tick boxes. Just set it to as little or as much as you want.

**EDIT: Unsure why its launching command line apps. Have a look to see what you have set in the auto start. Does it tell you what its launching in the terminals?**

Bill

Comment: Thanks Bill - i just updated my question as you were writing your answer (sorry!).  I don't think it's the startup list that's the issue.